# Element Node object is converted to Text Node after XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, w3c

The first time I run this program I need to create the xml, I first create the file and create a Document object and then convert it to an Element object.

```
        xmlDoc = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
        xmlDoc +="<head>";
        xmlDoc +=  "</head>";

        Document xmlFile =  XmlParser.parseXmlString(xmlDoc);
        Element element = xmlFile.getDocumentElement();
```

I have already verified this with its NodeType code, but when I create the parent node it gives me the Element_Node == 1. I attach this node to the element object.

```
        Element newElement = xmlFile.createElement("parent");
        newElement.setAttribute("id", i);
        element.appendChild(newElement);
```

I will put the child in a parent if it isn't already a child of the parent element, I check for this, if it isn't a child yet I will create a new Node class and give it text content.

```
            Node newChild = xmlFile.createElement("child");
            newChild.setTextContent(text);
            newElement.appendChild(newChild);
```

Then I will save this file with a transformer.

```
 Transformer transformer = null;
        try {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlFile);
        StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
        try {
            transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file.getPath())));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now the second time I run the program I will parse straight from this file. The XML file that was created has the structure below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<head>
<parent id="1">
<child>text1</child>
<child>text2</child>
<child>text3</child>
</parent>
<parent id="2">
<child>text1</child>
<child>text2</child>
</parent>
</head>
```

now that the file is created, the file will be read then parsed to create the element instead of the hard coded string.

```
xmlDoc = this.readFile(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Document xmlFile =  XmlParser.parseXmlString(xmlDoc);
Element element = xmlFile.getDocumentElement();
...
 String readFile(File file, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), charset);
```

The problem is now the parent element cannot be casted as a Element and has the Text_Node type value == 3. The following object cannot be casted.

```
Element nextSib = (Element) element.getFirstChild();
```

The idea is that now I can append a relevant child to a parent by going through each parent node which is why I need to obtain it in Element form so I can use the id attribute. But I cannot do this since the parent node is converted to a text node for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use the indentation when writing out a tree there will be white space between element nodes so a child node can be a text node with white space. If you are looking for the first element child node either use XPath `*[1]` or simply the name of the element `foo[1]` or if you want to do it with `childNodes` make sure you check the nodeType until you have an element node.

Comment: Alternatively, serialize the file without indentation.